# Bad Request: PARTICIPANT_ID_INVALID

Tags: python, telebot

`Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: PARTICIPANT_ID_INVALID`
Когда пытаюсь забанить юзера в своих чатах и каналах, иногда выдаёт такую ошибку и не банит.
Проблема возникает не всегда. Вариант того, что пользователь должен быть подписан на канал/чат отпадает, его проверял. ID тоже корректный

```
for i in range(len(chats_for_ban_id)):
   bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id, id_user)
```

Comment: Что за странный код? Откуда чат айди? Откуда юзер айди?

Comment: я привел пример метода, которым баню, откуда эти данные особого значения не имеет

Comment: тут больше не по коду вопросы, а по самой системе телеграм, потому что этот же самый код пользователей с нормальным id банит

Comment: Понимаете, эта ошибка говорит что юзер айди некорректный, потому я и спрашиваю откуда вы их берете. Возможно вы пытаетесь взять юзера из другого чата, а может этого юзера уже нет в нем вовсе.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что бот может банить только тех, кто состоит в чате?

Comment: Это звучит разумно, разве нет?

Comment: Вот да, звучит то это разумно, но бот умееет банить людей, не состоявших чате, я это проверял и работает как то через раз

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940269/9441900

Comment: Говорят, что бот не банит тех кого он не видел.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает, что ваш бот не видел этого пользователя раньше.

Например, мой userID `109780439`, вы можете попробовать `get_chat_member` с `@PublicTestGroup`, он должен ответить ошибкой.

А затем, перешлите ЛЮБОЕ мое сообщение (например, это) вашему боту, и вы получите другой результат :)

Перевод из SO [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940269/9441900)